# Some icons in Semantic-UI not working

Tags: css, icons, semantic-ui

I am using [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) to design a web theme and I have noticed that some icons do not load, most are working fine but some of the ones that don't work are `write` and `write square`.

Here is a [link](http://www.talk.hostoi.com/Semantic-UI/examples/homepage.html) to the site

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="ui page grid overview segment">
        <div class="ui two wide column"></div>
        <div class="twelve wide column">
          <div class="ui three column center aligned stackable divided grid">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="ui icon header">
                <i class="circular book link icon"></i>
                Stories 
              </div>
              <p>Read thousands of stories written and published by our amazing authors.</p>
              <p><a class="ui teal right labeled icon button" href="#">Read <i class="right long arrow icon"></i></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="ui icon header">
                <i class="circular write link icon"></i>

                Library
              </div>
              <p>Dig through our cat library to found out amazing things you can do with your kitty.</p>
              <p><a class="ui teal right labeled icon button" href="#">Write <i class="right long arrow icon"></i></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="ui icon header">
                <i class="circular user link icon"></i>
                Community
              </div>
              <p>Get feedback on your cat from a community of loving pet owners on our online bulletin board system.</p>
              <p><a class="ui teal right labeled icon button" href="#">Collaborate <i class="right long arrow icon"></i></a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the webpage in Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131
[image]

In Firefox 34.0.5
[image]

Don't have a clue why this is happening, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue with the same icons!

Comment: what version of semantic ui are you using? Mine appears to be * Version: 0.19.0

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with the same icons not showing.

I found that this was a version issue.

Switching to the brand new semantic-ui version 2.0 fixed the problem for me.